# Getting error when creating calculated columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, calculated-column-formula

I am trying create a simple calculated column, but I am getting an error:

> The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported

The formula looks like:

```
=DATE(YEAR([RevisjonsDato])+1,MONTH([RevisjonsDato]),DAY([RevisjonsDato]))
```

Can any one see what I am doing wrong in the formula?

Comment: In some countries you need to replace ',' with ';'. Otherwise I don't see any issue for now. Will check it.

Comment: Pretty sure @HappySPUser is correct about using `;` instead of `,` for the Nordic languages

Answer (score 2):

I've tested it with your formula and it worked well [image: Result of calculated column testing]

I suggest to try to change the commas with semicolons.

For testing any calculation you can use Excel as the possible commands are nearly equal. (in SharePoint there are a bit less possibilities)

Comment: Changing the commas with semicolons helped me. Greetings from the Netherlands.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Also when working with calculated columns I find it rather usefull to 'design' the formula in excel first. That way youy get better error handling compared to SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

the Formula is correct. i think the probleme come from the Column "RevisjonsDato". the column "RevisjonsDato" must be a date Column.